# Load a scaled down/low resolution image in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have small sized `<img>` in which I put very large pictures. This makes image loading slow and is a waste since I dont really need to download the whole big picture, I show it in very small size.

Is there a way to make HTML load lower resolution images instead of full image resolution? so the loading will be quicker.

Comment: You could store thumbnails on the server and load those, or you could use a server-side language to create dynamic thumbnails from the small images.

Comment: why don't you just put smaller pictures in there?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature of HTML (that I am aware of) that automatically generates a thumbnail sized image for you for faster loading. Some sites will do that automatically when you upload like on Wordpress or various e-commerce solutions. So unless you are using one of those, you will have to do your own image re-sizing, before you upload, or write your own feature of the site that resizes images on the fly on the server side.

You have to do this work on the server side, since HTML/CSS/JS are all client side only (node.js non-withstanding) and could only do the resizing for you once the image was already downloaded, which defeats the purpose.